# express-session can't send sessionId to browser as a cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, express-session

I got stuck on this problem, So I have my nodejs express app that run over http:// localhost:4000, and my vite React app that run over http:// localhost:5173.

The problem is my express app can't send the cookie containing express-session's sessionId to the browser, so there's no cookie in my web page.

This is my express app configuration:

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    store: store,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: "auto",
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60, // 1000ms * 60 * 60 =  1 jam
      sameSite: "none",
    },
  })
);
```

and this is how i fetch to my app from react with axios:

```js
let input = {
  userId: `${userId}`,
  password: `${password}`,
};

let inputJson = JSON.stringify(input);

axios
.post(`${api}/user/login`, inputJson, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
})
.then((response) => {})
.catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
```

After fetching to the api with correct input json, here is what my browser cookie looks like:
[react's web cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRqMd.png)

the cookie i made with res.cookie() is sent correctly, but the cookie from express-session is not.

here is how i set the cookies:

```js
res.cookie("user", "gnomgnom");
req.session.userId = userId;
```

but there's is something made me more confused, from the same express route controller (api/user/login)

i tried to do `console.log(req)`, and there I got the right sessions in it's header, also another cookie i set. But the session cookie is not pass to my react web.

```js
// from console.log(req) it has different sessionId every request.
...
session: Session {
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      _expires: 2023-12-23T14:46:13.267Z,
      originalMaxAge: 3600000,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: 'none'
    },
    userId: 'userId',
  },
...
```

So can someone help me solve this confusing problem of mine, Im really lost here...
Thanks.

Comment: What's `secure: "auto"` supposed to mean? Be aware that, in Chromium-based browsers, a cookie marked `SameSite=None` also requires `Secure`. Such browsers silently ignore attempts to set a cookie that contravene this requirement.